# Lua script code doesn't work on Battlefield1

Tags: lua, scripting, logitech-gaming-software

Trying to use this simple recoil reducer lua script code. But in game, cursor doesn't move in x axis. It kinda stucks in y axis.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
 
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3)then
            repeat  
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,1)
                        Sleep(33)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end             
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end     
    end
end
```

I tried to use older versions of Logitech G Hub. But same result. Currently I am using 2021.11.1775 version of Logitech G Hub.

Here is a video: https://youtu.be/ZJixURBzsyA

Comment: What line would you expect to move in the X axis?

Comment: @Luke100000 I mean the crosshair doesn't move in X axis while shooting. The code reduces the recoil but for example while shooting a moving target my aim stucks. It works fine in other softwares tho.

Comment: I still do not understand the problem after viewing the video.  I do not see a crosshair on the video.  What exactly should move on X axis?

Comment: @ESkri You can notice, it kinda stucks when I look right and left while I am pressing mouse1.

Comment: And it stucks this way ONLY when you run the game with this Lua script?

Comment: @ESkri ONLY in that game, it works fine in other apps

Comment: Is the problem disappears when you remove (disable) the Lua script?  Is the problem disappears when you comment the line `MoveMouseRelative(0,1)` ?

Comment: @ESkri It disappears but it is the main line for reducing recoil for such games.

Comment: Probably you can do nothing in GHub to solve the issue.

Comment: @ESkri It was actually working before a GHub update. I solved this problem by installing an older version. I formatted my pc 2 months ago and now the old version doesn't work too.